# Js files are merged as single file production mode. How to load it separeately

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have one done one rails project in that js files are merged into single js file i want to load it separately. How can i do that

Answer (score 0):

The way out of this is in your production.rb file of your environments folder in rails 
make it the settings as

```
    config.assets.compile = false
```

set the config assets recompile to false this will load the js file that you want to load separately